# Lifetime of ViewBag elements in ASP.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, viewbag

When will the values of the `ViewBag` be flushed or cleared ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you leave the view on subsequent request. `ViewBag` is created in the controller and it will live until the rendering of the view. In addition to this it is something that I would not recommend you using and replace it with view models.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend ViewBag? because of it live until the rending of view ?

Comment: Because it is much nicer to have a strongly typed ViewModel. Makes testing a lot easier.

Comment: Strongly type all the things!

Comment: Dynamic vs static, it's just a preference thing

Comment: If you want everything dynamic then go and use Ruby on Rails. Us C#'ers like our statically-typed goodness. :)