# Returning both Partial View and a Message

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partialview where it's possible to change a Connection String. When submitting an `Edit` action is called. From here I want to either return and re-open the partial view if I want the user to have a second go. If everything went well (or crashing) I want to call my JavaScript function `Logout`, that logs the user out and redirect to some startpage.

Both solutions works, just not together. I'm clearly missing some best practice, what should I do?

**Partial View: EditSetting**

```
@model WebConsole.ViewModels.Setting.SettingViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Setting", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "div" }, new { id = "editform" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" value=""/>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataSource, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataSource, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataSource, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InitialCatalog, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InitialCatalog, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InitialCatalog, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**JavaScript: Submit**

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    var $self = $(this);

    if ($(this).valid()) {

        // Change Connection String
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (message) {

                // Use Partial View
                //$('#myModal .modal-body').html(message);

                // Conn Str is now changed. Log out and redirect
                logOut($self, message);
            },
            error: function (message) {
                logOut($self, message);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

**Action: Edit**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SettingViewModel model)
{
    // Validate inputs
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", @"Not all inputs are valid.");
        return PartialView("EditSetting", model);
    }

    var sql = new DAL.SQL(DAL.SQL.GenerateConnectionString(model.DataSource, model.InitialCatalog, model.User, SecurePassword(model.Password)));

    // Validate Connection String
    if (!sql.Open())
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", @"Error. Unable to open connection to Database.");
        return PartialView("EditSetting", model);
    }

    // Validate a transaction
    if (!sql.IsRunningTransact())
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", @"Error. Unable to connect to Database Server.");
        return PartialView("EditSetting", model);
    }

    // Save Connection String
    BuildAndEncryptConnString(model);

    return Content("The Connection String is changed. Log in again to continue.");
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5359628/5071902

Comment: @RenanAraújo I don't need to render the view as a string. I need to know client-side if my result(message) there is returned from the action, is a partial view i need to render again, or it's a message i need to prompt to the user, before I log the user out and redirect him to the startpage. :)

Comment: @RenanAraújo Please tell me if i'm wrong, I just say it as I see it as for now. Maybe I don't understand it yet.

Comment: Hi @radbyx I posted an answer, It was too long to say in a comment :)

Comment: The real hidden bug was here, I found it after 2½ days! "UpdateTargetId = "div"", for somehow it doesn't work with "$('#myModal .modal-body').html(message);" The partial view is rendered and it looks like everything is fine, but the SECOND ajax call don't return. It does now with using the "UpdateTargetId". :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the extension method [RenderToString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19208941/5071902) and basead on [cacois answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5359628/5071902), you can create your action like this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(SettingViewModel model)
{
    // "Ifs" to return only partials
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView("EditSetting", model);
    }

    ...

    // Returning a Json with status (success, error, etc), message, and the content of 
    // your ajax, in your case will be a PartialView in string
    return Json(new { 
               Status = 1, 
               Message = "error message", 
               AjaxReturn = PartialView("EditSetting", model).RenderToString()});
}
```

Ps. I suggest you to create a model to define the Ajax return, with `Status`, `Message` and `AjaxReturn`. With that, your ajax requests will always return the same object type. For the `Status` property you can create a Enum.

Your ajax request, will be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: this.method,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.Message == undefined) {
            // Use data like a partial
        } else {
            // Use data.Message for the message and data.AjaxReturn for the partial
        }
    },
    error: function (message) {
        logOut($self, message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of "AjaxReturn = RenderViewToString(PartialView("EditSetting", model))});" did you mean: "AjaxReturn = RenderViewToString(PartialView("EditSetting", model).ViewName, model)});"

Comment: Your code works with the edit I made except in the case where the user misstyped a input wrong in the first attempt. Maybe it's my edit, where I used the ".ViewName" or it might be the "$self" that isn't remembered anymore in the javascript Closure, I don't know?

Comment: You are correct, to use that method you need to use it like you did. I changed the method to `RenderToString` created by Ted Nyberg, I think it's more cleaner now

Comment: So finially it all works. Your code was correct but I updated the DOM element wrong. I should have used the "TargetUpdateId" instead. Before did my second ajax call never called back to "success" for some weird reason I know about?!

Comment: RenanAraújo It doesn't seems like the ModelState errors can be showned this way. Controller: ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, @"Not all inputs are valid."); View: @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }).                             $('#updateTargetEditSetting').html(data.AjaxReturn);
                            //$('#myModal .modal-body').html(data.AjaxReturn); (this will show the errors, but then if I do another ajax call it wont be returned to 'success' for some weird reason I can't figure out, any ideas? :)

Comment: Ahh I was missing "form" here :$('#myModal .modal-body form').html(message);

Answer (score 0):

You can Return the Patial View, and Intialize ViewBag and assign the message to it, then in the view check if have value and show it if true.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(SettingViewModel model)
{
    // Put the ViewBag where ever you want
    ViewBag.ErrorMsg =" Error";
    return PartialView("EditSetting", model);
}
```

View:

```
@if(ViewBag.ErrorMsg !=null )
{
    <div>@ViewBag.ErrorMsg</div>
}
```

I hope that helped.

Comment: Yes i thought of that too just using the Model. I thought it was a hack, but might just be fine, I'll give it a try - thanks :)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov The MVC god, do NOT recommend ViewBag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858723/lifetime-of-viewbag-elements-in-asp-net-mvc3

Comment: Yes do not use ViewBag, but the idea of setting "something" in the action, the JavaScript can use to either do one thing or the other can still be applied I think. I still open to other answers if there is a better one? :)

Answer (score 0):

Add error handling to your ViewModel:

```
bool hasErrors;
string errorMessage;
```

In your controller, if the data validation is ok, just return the PartialView or `return RedirectToAction("Index");`. If not, set `hasErros = true;` and a custom `errorMessage`.

In the view, place an error block someone where the user will see it:

```
@if (Model.hasErrors)
{
   <div>Model.errorMessage</div>
}
```

By the way, you can do the data validation inside the ViewModel constructor.